# how to set up datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker

I can't seem to set this jquery datetimepicker. I believe I am following the instructions correctly. However, only the input box displays. After inspecting I saw these errors in the log

[image]

This the plugin I am trying to use.

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

previous code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

</script>
</head>
<body>
 

    
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
 
 
</body>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

So I found the original files here[enter link description here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-datetimepicker)

and then changed my code to the following

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.3.7/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

</script>
</head>
<body>
 

    
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
 
 
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.js" integrity="sha512-9yoLVdmrMyzsX6TyGOawljEm8rPoM5oNmdUiQvhJuJPTk1qoycCK7HdRWZ10vRRlDlUVhCA/ytqCy78+UujHng==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</html>
```

but now I have a new error. Any ideas on what I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind the order and dependencies of your scripts and use eventlisteners:

To make it simple:
Load CSS first (DateTimePicker), load JS second (jQuery, Datetimepicker), initialize an eventlistener using $().ready().

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>
  
  <!-- Load CSS first -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.3.7/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>
  
  <!-- Load JS second -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  
  <!-- Initialize JS, setup eventlistener(s) -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready($ => $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker());
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.3.7/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>

 
</head>
<body>
 

    
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
 
 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.js" integrity="sha512-9yoLVdmrMyzsX6TyGOawljEm8rPoM5oNmdUiQvhJuJPTk1qoycCK7HdRWZ10vRRlDlUVhCA/ytqCy78+UujHng==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> either this or the previous one not both-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above will fix all your issues about where to put scripts and what to load (you where both loading the extended and minified version of the library)

See the following snippet:

```js
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.3.7/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />


<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.js" integrity="sha512-9yoLVdmrMyzsX6TyGOawljEm8rPoM5oNmdUiQvhJuJPTk1qoycCK7HdRWZ10vRRlDlUVhCA/ytqCy78+UujHng==" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> either this or the previous one not both-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.newExpextedStartTime').click(function() {
    $(".ExpextedStartTime").focus();
  });
    $(".ExpextedStartTime").datetimepicker({ step: 20, format: "d/m/Y H:i", autoclose: true, buttonImage: "../../../Content/Images/ef_calendar_icon.png", showOnFocus: false, buttonImageOnly: true, startDate: new Date() })
    $("#ExpextedStartTime").val(moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"));
});
```

```css
.xdsoft_datetimepicker {left: 0px !important;}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_default, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box>div>div.xdsoft_current {
    background: grey !important;
    box-shadow: grey 0 1px 3px 0 inset !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_today {
color: darkgrey!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<div class="input-group date" style="width: 50%;">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control ExpextedStartTime valid" id="ExpextedStartTime" isiteditable="True" name="ExpextedStartTime" placeholder="dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="input-group-addon  ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar newExpextedStartTime"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Load CSS (DateTimePicker) first, then load JS (jQuery, DatetimePicker), and set up an event listener using $().ready() to make it simple.